# How to replace image and data to all objects

Tags: texturing, uv, image

[image]

How to transfer all the uv, image and verts on other objects. Sith the single leaf uv, image, and verts I want to transfer on all the leaves without disturbing the shape of the leaves. I tried object data but all the leaf shapes get disturbed. Anyway or suggestion how it works.

[image]

Comment: All these leaves are different meshes and they have different unwrap, so I don't know if you can do it without rotating each UV of each leaf. The best would have been to use linked-duplications

Comment: You can't even make a Ctrl L > Link Object Data as all the objects have no rotation

Comment: There is a command allowing you to transfer UVs but, as moonboots said, it requires the 2 meshes with matching geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments - hard to say if transfer is possible ... for me mainly because of different topology, but you can achieve that by a different way ...

Select all leaves objects, go to edit mode *Unwrapp* > **Smart UV Project** ... and Scale UV down to fit image texture.

[image]